# Restrict indexing and remove current indexes

Tags: .htaccess, search, indexing, robots.txt

I have looked through few questions on this topic, but I am still not sure if I am getting this right.

I have got a php file which returns xml/json responses based on the GET parameters.

```
http://someDomain.com/get.php?param=option1
```

Google has indexed quite a few of those urls already.

As I understand I can restrict robots from indexing any further urls on someDomain.com by adding someDomain.com/robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *
```

I understand that by adding robots.txt search engines will not be able to see the `noindex` meta to remove the current indexed urls.

But the get.php is not returning any meta/head information anyway, becuse it only returns json/xml data.

So how can I get google to remove the already indexed urls from search results?

Comment: Use a 301 redirect for google bot

Comment: @Starkeen Do you mean something like: `Redirect 301 /get.php /blackwhole/` ? How can I redirect ONLY google bot and not anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

#If user agent is "googlebot"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC]
#And query string is "param=anychar"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=(.+)$ [NC]
#Then 301 redirect "get.php" to "/backwhole"
RewriteRule ^get\.php$ /backwhole [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a quick sub question: What would I put in /blackhole folder? index.php file outputting a `forbidden` header ? Instead of redirecting and creating the folder just for that, how can I make this  htaccess file to return the `forbidden` or some similar header? Is it possible?

Comment: please could you clarify? That 'blackwhole' was just an example. It still doesn't fully anser my question.